# Is it possible to get highcharts range selector to work with jQuery timepicker, like it works with jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, highcharts, range, selector, timepicker

I have following 4 HTML elements in a flex-container

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <SELECT class="stack foo" id="list">
    <OPTION VALUE="All">All</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Urgent">Urgent</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Continuous netting">Continuous netting</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="Scheduled netting">Scheduled netting</OPTION>
  </SELECT>

  <div class="foo">
    <input type="text" value="Select Hour" class="timepicker" />
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <span>To</span>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <input type="text" value="Select Hour" class="timepicker" />
  </div>
</div>


<div id="container3"></div>
```

When selecting hour from and to, it would be great to be able to visualise the hour range similar to Highcharts in-build range selector property for Highstock, which also works with jQuery datepicker: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/611/)

Is there a way to bind timepicker with range selector?

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/gxrmahp9/)

```
$('input.timepicker').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
  minTime: '06:00', // 11:45:00 AM,
  maxTime: '18:00',
  maxHour: 24,
  maxMinutes: 30,
  startTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0), // 3:00:00 PM - noon
  interval: 30 // 30 minutes
});

// load chart when page is ready: loadData
$(function() {

  loadData();

  // load chart when on change load-data: loadData    

  $("select.stack").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    if (selectedCountry === "All") {
      loadData();
    } else {
      return false
    }
  });

  function loadData() {

    var options = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container3',
        type: 'column'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        showFirstLabel: true,
        showLastLabel: true,
        min: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
        minRange: 3600 * 1000,
        labels: {
          format: '{value:%H:%M}'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
        }
      },
      legend: {

      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],
        name: 'Urgent',
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
        data: [8, 24, 37, 42, 33, 60, 54, 22, 41, 16, 35, 18]
      }, {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
        name: 'Continuous netting',
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
        data: [61, 8, 15, 50, 67, 79, 83, 25, 22, 20, 74, 33]
      }, {
        name: 'Scheduled netting',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
        data: [21, 85, 18, 23, 81, 71, 87, 60, 15, 30, 59, 61]
      }]
    };
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


    $("#list").on('change', function() {
      //alert('f')
      var selVal = $("#list").val();
      if (selVal === "Urgent") {
        options.series = [{
          name: 'Urgent',
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[9],
          pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
          pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
          data: [61, 8, 15, 50, 67, 79, 83, 25, 22, 20, 74, 33]
        }]
      } else if (selVal === "Continuous netting") {
        options.series = [{
          name: 'Continuous netting',
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
          pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
          pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
          data: [21, 85, 18, 23, 81, 71, 87, 60, 15, 30, 59, 61]
        }]
      } else if (selVal === "Scheduled netting") {
        options.series = [{
          name: 'Scheduled netting',
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
          pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
          pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
          data: [21, 85, 18, 23, 81, 71, 87, 60, 15, 30, 59, 61]
        }]
      } else {
        return false
      }
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to achieve this effect by using the `setExtremes` feature with the getting values from your inputs.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes